# How to use page session value and function in Jquery webmethod

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net

I have a session value and a function in a apsx.cs page and I am using jquery webmethod to insert data into database.

Now i want to access session value and function in webmethod but it gives some error.

Below is my Page load code:

```
int nUserId = Convert.ToInt16(Session["UId"]);
```

And a Function :

```
    public int CalcUser()
    {
       return Convert.ToInt16(Session["UId"]) * 2;
    }
```

Now below is my Webmethod:

```
    [WebMethod]
    public static void Save()
    {
        UserInfo objUser = new UserInfo();
        objUser.Useid = Convert.ToInt16(Session["UId"]);
        objUser.CalcUser = CalcUser();
        ... Save into Database           
    }
```

So how can I use session value and function in webmwthod.

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to explicitly state that you want to use `Session` with your ASP.NET AJAX Page Method by using the `EnableSession= true` value in the `WebMethod` attribute, like this:

```
[WebMethod(EnableSession = true)]
public static void Save()
{
    UserInfo objUser = new UserInfo();
    objUser.Useid = Convert.ToInt16(HttpContext.Current.Session["UId"]);
    objUser.CalcUser = CalcUser();
    ... Save into Database           
}
```

---

> Note: You must fully qualify the namespace of the session (`HttpContext.Current.Session`).

---

To use the `CalcUser()` function you need to make it `static` and fully qualify the `Session` object, like this:

```
public static int CalcUser()
{
   return Convert.ToInt16(HttpContext.Current.Session["UId"]) * 2;
}
```

---

> Note: ASP.NET AJAX Page Methods only have access to `static` methods, as there is no instance of the page (or any class for that matter).

Comment: Hi For Session it works fine but how can I use CalcUser() function in webmethod.

Comment: To use the `CalcUser()` method you need to make it `static`, see updated answer.

Comment: @Hitesh - glad it is working for you. Feel free to up-vote the answer as well. :-)

Answer (score 0):

You need to use `[WebMethod(EnableSession = true)]` on webmethod

Then you can use like `Context.Session["key"]`

```
    [WebMethod]
    [WebMethod(EnableSession = true)]
    public static void Save()
    {
        UserInfo objUser = new UserInfo();
        objUser.Useid = Convert.ToInt16(Context.Session["UId"]);
        objUser.CalcUser = CalcUser();
        ... Save into Database           
    }
```